# Access to a pushed controller from navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I try to set some properties from a pushed viewcontroller (Viewcontroller B) to the previous view in the stack of the nav controller (Viewcontroller A).

However the object (header) I try to set properties is nil just at the moment where I set its properties. (checked with breakpoints)

ViewControllerB.m

```
 breapoint 1 -> ViewControllerA * missionVC = (ViewControllerA *) self.navigationController.viewControllers[n-2];



breakpoint 2 ->missionVC.header.title = companyName;
missionVC.header.subTitle = missionName;

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

at breakpoint 1, the missionVC has the header Object correctly initialized, but at the breakpoint 2 missionVC.header is nil and I don't know why.

Comment: You are creating new object of previous view controller. You should pass a reference of Viewcontroller A to B and then set the value of viewcontroller A. Either you can use delegate to pass object.

Comment: I thought I retrived the previous and not create a new one, thank you

Comment: What that min? You have already pass reference of View controller A to B.

Comment: Yes now I passed a reference of A to B, in B I set properties of the reference, and I relaunch A

Comment: Try setting the properties after you relaunch A. i.e after you pop.

Comment: If my answer help you. Then please select the answer as accepted and make up vote.

Comment: The object where I try to set properties is still nil after pop

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new object of previous view controller. You should pass a reference of Viewcontroller A to B and then set the value of viewcontroller A. Either you can use delegate to pass object.